# products don't get added to shopping cart

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm working on **onlineshop.php** page that is supposed to display forms, each form has a product with"add to cart button". The products get displayed, but the problem is that the product i choose doesn't get added to the cart. i don't know if it's a problem in the query or the code itself.

**onlineshop.php:**

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('connection.php');

if ( isSet($_POST['Pro_ID'], $_POST['Price'] , $_POST['Pro_Name'] ) ) 
{
    $qry="INSERT INTO shopping_cart(Cart_Name,Pro_Name,Pro_ID,Price) VALUES ( 'dzfgtdfxdf','$_POST[Pro_Name]','$_POST[Pro_ID]' ,  '$_POST[Price]'  ) ";                 
    $qry = 'SELECT * FROM product' ;
}
else            
    $qry = 'SELECT * FROM product' ;
    //Run QUERY
    $result = mysql_query ($qry);
?> 


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Online Shop</title>



    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">

<div class="wrapper">
<div style="z-index:10;float:right;top:20px;    position: relative;font-size:10px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="shoppingcart.php"><img src="cartt.png" alt="ٍاخححهىل }شقف" style="width:40px;height:40px"><br/>Shopping Cart</a></div>
    <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png"  alt="logo" height="162px"width="800px"  style="border-style:none" title="Home"/></a></div>



    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->


            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

          <ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>

  </li>  
  <li class="sousMenu"><a>Book/Cancel an appointment</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="book.html">Book an appointment</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="cancel.html">Cancel an appointment</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="onlineshop.html">Online Shop</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="viewcatalogue.html">View Catalogue</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="aboutus.html">About us</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="managerlogin.html">Manager log-in</a>
  </li>
</ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
 <div id="boxcontainer">
<div class="contentboxes1">








        <div class="row">
            <div class="box">


                <div class="col-lg-12">

             <h2 style="text-align:center; color:#ab4b4b;">Online Shop</h2>


                    <hr class="visible-xs">             <br/>


                 <center><div style="left:100px;display:inline;"><select name="categories"
<option value="hair">Hair products</option>
<option value="makeup">Makeup</option>
<option value="nail">Nail Products</option>
<option value="skin">Skin Care</option>
</select></div>

    <form action="demo_form.asp"style="display:inline;" >
  <input type="search" name="searchSpecilist">
  <input type="submit" value="Search" style="float:none;    width: 70px; height: 20px;">
</form> <br><br><br></center>
<?php



if($result) {
$did = 0;
Print " <table style='width:100%'>";

while($info=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if($did==0){

Print"
<tr>
<td>
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' style='display:inline;' action=''  >

    <figure>
  <img src='B7Brush.jpg'  alt='The Pulpit Rock' width='130' height='130' style='left:00px;top:00px; '>
  <figcaption style='text-align:center;'><b>".$info['Pro_Name']."</b><br/>".$info['Price']."<p style='color:green;'>".$info['Availability']."</p><p style='font-size:13px;display:inline'>Quantity:</p>
  <input type='number' name='quantity' min='1' max='10' style='width:3em;'></figcaption>
</figure>

<input type='hidden' name='Pro_ID' value='".$info['Pro_ID']."' />
<input type='hidden' name='Price' value='".$info['Price']."' />
<input type='hidden' name='Pro_ID' value='".$info['Pro_Name']."' />
<input type='hidden' name='Availability' value='".$info['Availability']."' />



<input name='button1' type='submit' value='Add To Cart' style='width:8em;   ' />
</form>
</td> ";
$did++;


continue; }

if($did==1){
Print "
<td>
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' style='display:inline;' action=''  >

   <figure>
  <img src='eye.jpg'  alt='The Pulpit Rock' width='130' height='130' style='left:00px;top:00px; '>
  <figcaption style='text-align:center;'><b>".$info['Pro_Name']."</b><br/>".$info['Price']."<p style='color:green;'>".$info['Availability']."</p><p style='font-size:13px;display:inline'>Quantity:</p>
  <input type='number' name='quantity' min='1' max='10' style='width:3em;'></figcaption>
</figure>

<input type='hidden' name='Pro_ID' value='".$info['Pro_ID']."' />
<input type='hidden' name='Price' value='".$info['Price']."' />
<input type='hidden' name='Pro_ID' value='".$info['Pro_Name']."' />
<input type='hidden' name='Availability' value='".$info['Availability']."' />
<input name='button1' type='submit' value='Add To Cart' style='width:8em;   ' />
</form>
</td>";
$did++;
continue; }
if($did==2){
Print"
<td>
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' style='display:inline;' action=''  >

    <figure>
  <img src='korres.jpg'  alt='The Pulpit Rock' width='130' height='130' style='left:00px;top:00px; '>
  <figcaption style='text-align:center;'><b>".$info['Pro_Name']."</b><br/>".$info['Price']."<p style='color:green;'>".$info['Availability']."</p><p style='font-size:13px;display:inline'>Quantity:</p>
  <input type='number' name='quantity' min='1' max='10' style='width:3em;'></figcaption>
</figure>

<input type='hidden' name='Pro_ID' value='".$info['Pro_ID']."' />
<input type='hidden' name='Price' value='".$info['Price']."' />
<input type='hidden' name='Pro_ID' value='".$info['Pro_Name']."' />
<input type='hidden' name='Availability' value='".$info['Availability']."' />
<input name='button1' type='submit' value='Add To Cart' style='width:8em;   ' />
</form>
</td>";
$did++;
continue; }

if($did==3){

Print"
<td>
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' style='display:inline;' action=''  >

   <figure>
  <img src='self.jpg'  alt='The Pulpit Rock' width='130' height='130' style='left:00px;top:00px; '>
  <figcaption style='text-align:center;'><b>".$info['Pro_Name']."</b><br/>".$info['Price']."<p style='color:green;'>".$info['Availability']."</p><p style='font-size:13px;display:inline'>Quantity:</p>
  <input type='number' name='quantity' min='1' max='10' style='width:3em;'></figcaption>
</figure>

<input type='hidden' name='Pro_ID' value='".$info['Pro_ID']."' />
<input type='hidden' name='Price' value='".$info['Price']."' />
<input type='hidden' name='Pro_ID' value='".$info['Pro_Name']."' />
<input type='hidden' name='Availability' value='".$info['Availability']."' />


<input name='button1' type='submit' value='Add To Cart' style='width:8em;   ' />
</form>
</td> </tr>";
$did=0;

}
}

Print " </table>";

}

else echo "Your cart is empty";

    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


  <div style="font-size:8px;">

                    <p style="display:inline;">Copyright &copy; SOFTWARE II KSU 2014. <br><a href="Sitemap.html">Sitemap</a> </p>  <div style="z-index:10;float:right;">           <img src="img/instagram.png" alt="instagram" style="width:30px;height:30px">&nbsp;<img src="img/facebook.png" alt="facebook" style="width:30px;height:30px">&nbsp;<img src="img/twitter.png" alt="twitter" style="width:30px;height:30px"></div>
                </div>
    </div>

</div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
</body>

</html>
</html>
<?php 
// close database connection
mysql_close ($con);
?>
```

Comment: put else statements in a block `{`  `}`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: The `INSERT INTO shopping_cart` query does not seem to be executed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if ( isSet
```

to

if ( isset

Removing the capital letter and replacing it with lowercase

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you compose the `INSERT` query but you don't run it. Use function `mysql_query()` to send the query to the MySQL server to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are overwriting the $qry variable before you execute the INSERT.

So you are never inserting the data into the table, you are just selecting it.

Run the INSERT before you SELECT and it should work.

Comment: i put       $result = mysql_query ($qry);
 right after insert but it's still not working

Comment: did you also change isSet to isset like the other answer suggested, and are you sure you are posting all the appropriate items that you are looking for? Another words, are you sure that you are actually executing that code or is it just skipping and going to the else?

Try putting 

`echo "test";
exit();`

Above the INSERT statement and see if it fires.

Comment: could you explain your last point?    is this line wrong:  if ( isset($_POST['Pro_ID'], $_POST['Price'] , $_POST['Pro_Name'] ) ) ?? how do i know if it executes?

Comment: No the line is not wrong, I am just asking are you sure that you really are posting all those things? If you are not, then of course your INSERT won't execute, because php will skip it and go to the else portion.

If you place the code I suggested above `echo "test"; exit();` then your page should go white, and just have `test` on it. If not then you are not passing the isset(). You can also use Firebug on Firefox to inspect the variables your are posting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('connection.php');

                    if ( isset($_POST['Pro_ID'], $_POST['Price'] , $_POST['Pro_Name'] ) ) {


                    $qry="INSERT INTO shopping_cart(Cart_Name,Pro_Name,Pro_ID,Price) VALUES ( 'dzfgtdfxdf','$_POST[Pro_Name]','$_POST[Pro_ID]' ,  '$_POST[Price]'  ) ";

                        // 1) Run your SQL
                        mysql_query($qry);
                    }
                    // Actually, You don't need ELSE block statement, because this lines of code repeats in IF block, and in ELSE block.
                        $qry = 'SELECT * FROM product' ;
                    //Run QUERY
                    $result = mysql_query ($qry);



  ?>
```